# Printing Ant target execution time

Tags: ant

I want to print the execution time taken for each individual Ant target and its dependent targets.

```
<target name="target1" depends="target2, target3"> 
....
</target>
```

When run should show following output

```
Target 2 - x seconds
Target 3 - y seconds
Target 1 - z seconds
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Since Ant 1.8.0 you can use a [profilelogger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#ProfileLogger) to do this.

```
ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.ProfileLogger target
```

Produces output like

> Target aTarget: started Thu Jan 22
>   09:01:00 CET 2009
>
> echo: started Thu Jan 22 09:01:00 CET
>   2009
>        [echo] echo-task
>
> echo: finishedThu Jan 22 09:01:00 CET
>   2009 (250ms)
>
> zip: started Thu Jan 22 09:01:00 CET
>   2009
>         [zip] Building zip: ...\my.zip
>
> zip: finishedThu Jan 22 09:01:01 CET
>   2009 (1313ms)
>
> Target aTarget: finishedThu Jan 22
>   09:01:01 CET 2009 (1719ms)

Answer (score 8):

Use one of the listeners from Ant add-on task collections:

- [antutility](https://antutility.dev.java.net/)
- [antelope](http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03ch27.html)
- [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/performance_monitor.html) 
  With `-listener net.sf.antcontrib.perf.AntPerformanceListener`

Or check their sources, and roll your own listener.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ant-contrib, then there is a stopwatch task. Put it at the top and bottom of each target and it will report the elapsed and total times.

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There is the `TStamp` task that you can use to demark your other tasks.

See here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html

There is some extension/addon that will do it all for you without having to do this. Will scrabble around for it if no-one comes up with it first.