# Profiling complex ant build scripts: How to find bottlenecks?

Tags: java, ant, profiling, build-process

My goal is to decrease the build times of our system. We are using Ant, and the build system built on top of it is quite complex.

To find bottlenecks, it would be great to display the elapsed times of the most expensive tasks. Do you know of a wrapper for Ant that is capable of doing that? Something like a profiler for Ant tasks.

For those, who a familiar with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/): I'm looking for a tool like [time-grunt](https://github.com/sindresorhus/time-grunt).

---

(At the moment, my strategy is to look at time-stamped console outputs to get an idea of the bottlenecks.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Ant target execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250204/printing-ant-target-execution-time)

Comment: Since Ant 1.8.0 you can use a profilelogger to do this.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, that answer is indeed very helpful.